# What's the point of Incremental Find in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext

At the end of this tutorial: ***https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICxMZGLKEbU*** the author makes it look like the **Incremental Find (CTRL+I)** is somehow a quicker way to get one's cursor from anywhere in the edited document to some specified place than when using the **Regular Find (CTR+F)**, but I fail to see any difference in the number of steps required. You hit the keys, type a word to which you want to get to, and then either press ENTER (Incremental) or ESCAPE (Regular).

Also, I don't quite see why it's called *incremental*.

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Jesper From [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help], software questions are allowed if they cover "*[...] software tools commonly used by programmers*". Sublime Text, like vim, emacs, Notepad++, etc., is a programming editor, and there are [tens of thousands of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext2+or+sublimetext3+or+sublimetext+or+vim+or+vi+or+emacs+or+notepad%2b%2b) about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic.

Comment: I agree with @MattDMo, splitting Q's from a top programming tool into superuser *might* have had some level of consistency, but it would be inconvenient for the users: sublime text users are a near subset of the set of programmers.

Answer (score 27):

There is a slight difference in between the two functions. With `Find` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>), you type in what you're looking for, and each time you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the next occurrence of the pattern is shown, but it is not a selection in that you can begin typing right away - you need to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> first, and the highlighting is changed to a selection.

With `Incremental Find` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>), on the other hand, you start typing in your pattern, and when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `Find` highlighting is turned into a selection, the dialog box disappears, and you are immediately able to begin editing the selection. This saves a grand total of one keystroke over the `Find` method, but has the disadvantage that, unless you hit <kbd>F3</kbd> (`Find Next`), you are only editing the first instance of the pattern found.

It's kind of a subtle difference, and each one can be used in different situations. Play around with them both and see how each fits into your workflow.

Comment: also (sadly) "find_selected_text" does not work with incremental find

Comment: This feature would be very interesting if the incremental search woudl select every instance, not just the first.

Comment: The way you describe it, there is *not* one keystroke of savings... you just are hitting the ESCAPE key instead of the RETURN key when you're done searching and want to start typing.

Answer (score 7):

The only functional difference (other than using different keys) is that with incremental search you have the option of either going back to the original (pre-search) cursor position by hitting ESC or staying on the found result by hitting RETURN... whereas the full Find function does not give you the ability to go back to the original position (although you can easily do so with the Goto > Jump Back command after exiting your search).

So in the one very limited use-case of "I want to save 1 keystroke in the event that I want to go back to my original cursor position after searching and seeing what I found but not changing it at all", incremental search has the normal find functionality beat. However, to me this is a detriment because whenever I try incremental search, I wind up hitting that ESCAPE key by accident (because my muscle memory is so used to it from the normal Find functionality) and having to do the search over again.

Hence, practically speaking I think it's best to ignore the existence of Incremental Search. Why bother trying to teach your fingers a separate sequence of keyboard commands *and* an ever-so-slightly different mental model of how it works (but with no practical difference other than saving 1 keystroke in an edge-case at the expense of triggering it accidentally more often than you want it to actually happen on purpose)?

Historically speaking, I think incremental search is a holdover from older text editors that didn't have search functionality as well-done (IMO) as Sublime. (Actually I think Sublime v2's search interface didn't work as smoothly as v3 does, so maybe it was more helpful back in the old days of Sublime as well?)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `Ctrl+F` copies the behavior of the Find dialog as implemented in the majority of mainstream software. The Incremental search copies [Emacs' Incremental search](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Incremental-Search.html) functionality.

Answer (score -1):

The biggest advantage of incremental search is, it shortens the search operation in most cases. Say you want to find "shakespeare". With regular search you must type the whole 11 letters, while with incremental you will most possibly get to the word after typing the first few letters.